# Weight with Custom Options - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, custom-options

Is there a solution for adding weight to custom options? So that the overall product weight is adjusted based on custom options selected?

(Or is anyone aware of any extensions that can add this functionality?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Out of box, no, custom options do not support weight.

Bundled products do support dynamic weight and price based on selections, so they may be more appropriate for what you're trying to do.